# How do I create a mapping in vim to automate the ifdef commands for .h c++ file

Tags: c++, vim

How do I create a mapping in vim to automate the ifdef commands for .h c++ file?  Basically I want to have a mapping that will create the following that will work with .h and .hpp etc

```
#ifndef <filename>_<extension>__
#define <filename>_<extension>__

#endif  // <filename>_<extension>__
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just type the following in your .vimrc file. Your .vimrc file should be in your home directory. This will output what you are looking for. You can use this after editing a .h or .hpp file and just hit the `<f12>` key

```
nnoremap <f12> "%pF.r_A__<esc>I#ifndef <esc>gUwyypldwidefine <esc>yypldwiendif //<esc>O<esc>
inoremap <f12> <esc>"%pF.r_A__<esc>I#ifndef <esc>gUwyypldwidefine <esc>yypldwiendif //<esc>O<esc>i
```

Answer (score 1):

Also worth mentioning, abbreviations can also be used to do this sort of thing.  An example with a small helper function to make it easier to read

```
function! InsertHeaderGuard() 
    let def = expand('%:r') . '_' . expand('%:e') . '__'
    let guard =  '#ifndef ' . def . "\n"
    let guard .= '#define ' . def . "\n\n"
    let guard .= '#endif // ' . def 
    return guard
endfunction


iabbrev _TEST <c-r>=InsertHeaderGuard()<cr>
```

Comment: Or simply `inoreabbrev <expr> _TEST InsertHeaderGuard()` for the abbreviation.

Comment: Did not know about <expr>, thanks.  Seems more clear that way