# creating include guard in vim

Tags: c++, c, vim, c-preprocessor

Do you know an existing plugin in VIM to create automatically an include guard

```
 #ifndef <FILENAME>_<HPP or H>  // ..or similar
 #define 
 ... code
 #endif
```

based on the file name. Something that is part of a bigger plugin that helps in writing C/C++ code.

An even better solution is something that creates a C/C++ header and body files altogether.

I found thee custom sulotion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042690/how-do-i-create-a-mapping-in-vim-to-automate-the-ifdef-commands-for-h-c-file) but I am looking some plugin already used and widely accepted.

Comment: You mean as an include guard?

Comment: Yes. Include guard...I am editing the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one out:

https://github.com/drmikehenry/vim-headerguard/blob/master/plugin/headerguard.vim

I'm going to assume you know where to put your `.vim` files :p

Comment: Thanks Kepani! Yes I know  :D